# iOS find out when a user closes the app from the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm have a little troubles with my socket based chat application. When the user closes the app from the background (by hitting the home button twice and closing it) my server does not know that the user has actually closed the app, so it continues to send push notifications to that user.

How can i detect when a user actually closes the app from the background?

My server logic works like this:
When the user takes the app into the background my server sends push notifications instead of messages over the socket. If the app is in the foreground my server sends messages over the socket.

Any ideas how others are handling this?

Comment: use [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveNotificationForCitySelectedWithNotification:) name:kNotificationCitySelected object:nil];

Answer (score 2):

**Old answer**

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

is not called when the user closes the app in the background by hitting the home button twice and closing it.

I'm currently working on an app where I'm dealing with a similar (though not the same) situation…  In order to check to see whether a user is available/has a network connection, I'm posting to the server at regular intervals and only allowing my server to send push notifications if it's received a post from the user recently.  Likewise, maybe you could have the user's device post to the server to confirm receipt of message after every push notification then stop sending notifications if the user's device stops responding?

---

Edit:

**New Answer**

I could be wrong, but… This seems to have changed!  Looks like we've had an Apple angel looking over our shoulders!  Now applicationWillTerminate is in fact called when my app is closed in this way.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, this is not possible. Once you are in the background, the system can terminate you at any time without any further warning.

You need to use the applicationDidEnterBackground message (or UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification notification) to tell your server to close the socket connection and switch to  push notifications. That's what you want to do in any case, since your app can no longer signal the user once it's in the background.